# Boxplot with hover tool tip in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve a **Boxplot with hover tool tip in Python**
I have tried **bokeh.charts and bkcharts** which are deprecated and no module is found for the same.
I even tried **mpld3**, but all I got was **Scatter plot with the tooltip**,
I even tried the bokeh box plot https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/boxplot.html from here but it is very complex and making use of unnecessary groupby column.
If anyone has boxplot with hover tool tip in python than please help.
Similar functionality can be achieved very easily in R so why not in Python???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @KamilNaja it would be better to help rather than downvoting the ques

Answer (score -1):

did you try plotly?
[This example](https://plot.ly/~hanjingwang/4) may help.
You may have to add JS code so I'm aware this may not be what you need. Switch to tab "Python & R" and look at the Python code. There are comments there.